# ¿Hay un registro de actividad de comandos en git?

Tags: git, línea-de-comandos

La idea es ver un listado de todas las acciones o comandos que el usuario ha introducido sobre Git. Por ejemplo, para saber cómo he ido a parar a un commit, ver que comandos he introducido anteriormente y para poder entender mejor lo que ha hecho el sistema.

Normalmente tienes la consola como ayuda, en ella se pueden ver todos los comandos que uno ha usado, pero me han pasado situaciones en las que he cerrado a la consola y al volverla a abrir ya no podía ver qué comandos había introducido.

Comment: La respuesta valida para tu caso es realizar el `git reflog` como lo comenta abulafia, alli tienes en orden los comandos ejecutados en tu respositorio, si bien el history de `gnu/linux` puede funcionarte eres muy especifico en mencionar `git` de hecho el llegar al `history | grep ` aun no te garantiza que los comandos sean correctos pudiste ejecutarlo con otro usuario con permisos en el repositorio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es exactamente lo que preguntabas, pero puede ser más útil en tu caso.

Git tiene el comando [**`git reflog`**](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Herramientas-de-Git-Revisi%C3%B3n-por-selecci%C3%B3n#r_git_reflog) que te permite examinar el *reflog*, que es un log (registro) de todas las veces que ha cambiado alguna referencia dentro del repositorio. `HEAD` es una referencia, que cambia cada vez que haces un *checkout*,  o un *commit*, así que esas operaciones quedan "registradas" en el *reflog*.

Lo que es mejor, también quedan registrados los cambios mas "destructivos", como `git rebase` o `git reset`, lo que te permite volver a un commit al que no podrías volver de otro modo porque las cabezas de las ramas se hayan movido también.

Lo que no verás de esta forma son los `git status`,  `git log`,  `git add`, y otros que hayas podido hacer que no modifiquen referencias, pues esos no se guardan en el reflog.

Por otro lado, el uso de `history` sugerido en otras respuestas no deja de ser equivalente a pulsar "flecha arriba" muchas veces en una terminal, pues una vez que terminas con los comandos de esa sesión, seguirá con los que estén almacenados en el fichero `~/.bash_history`. El problema es que si tú no encuentras lo que buscabas a base de "flecha arriba", es porque no está guardado en ese fichero y por tanto tampoco te aparecerá con `history`.

La razón por la que pudo no guardarse es que ese fichero se escribe cuando sales de sesión. Si tenías varias terminales abiertas, la última que cierres sobreescribirá a lo que hiciste desde otras, y así puedes perder parte de la historia.

Answer (score 3):

Este no es para la historia de git, pero usando la historia de comandos en Linux puedes usar el comando `history` y filtrar los resultados con el comando `grep`, algo como esto:

```
history | grep "git"
```

Si necesitas buscar algo específico, como lo relacionado con el commando `commit` puedes usar:

```
history | grep "git commit"
```

Todos los comandos ejecutados por los usuario no quedan registrado, **solamente** las acciones que afectan el repositorio. Para esto está el comando `git log`. Con este podrías inferir los cambios que ha tenido en el tiempo.

Puedes usarlo así:

```
$ git log

commit bac651c6d739341f2e4085619500654ba5950a6e
Author: gustavovelascoh <gustavovelascoh@mail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 14 10:38:00 2018 +0000

    Updated .gitignore

commit 2a0afcd7a399e7e3e94e48fd954c976249137b18
Author: gustavovelascoh <ggustavovelascoh@mail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 14 10:34:01 2018 +0000

    First version of app

commit 44d581be49a0b268ea1d12f7cd5a60d84ddc2e95
Merge: 53a2702 613a787
Author: gustavovelascoh <gustavovelascoh@mail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 14 10:30:33 2018 +0000

    Merge branch 'master' of https://bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx
```

o con diferentes opciones de visualizacion como:

```
$ git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate

* bac651c (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Updated .gitignore
* 2a0afcd First version of app
*   44d581b Merge branch 'master' of https://bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx
|\  
| * 613a787 Added .gitignore and yield calculator script
| * f0bb412 Files updated. running version
* | 53a2702 Added configuration file support
* | 56191c3 Displaying seconds in X axis
|/  
* 94e143c (tag: v1.0) Added recording application
* 3174c94 Added recording example with unknown duration
* 6f793da Added CAN sniffer class
* 68128fa update utils and record_line
* 05449cb Added support for subprocess in windows
* 38ca880 Data is loaded and plotted
* 8e70927 Initial commit. Server, Recording and partial reading
```

Comment: y si es windows?, y si usa sourcetree?

Answer (score 1):

en linux puedes usar el comando `history`

```
history | grep git
```

Esto te mostrara los comando que incluyen la palabra git puedes ser mas especifico si quieres por ejemplo

```
history | grep git checkout

 doskey /history
```

Con la diferencia que la búsqueda sera manual